# Work locally on ASP.NET web project hosted that is hosted on VPS

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to learn how to use the ASP.NET framework; I'm already familiar with C# having already used it for desktop utilities a couple of times.

I have a hosted VPS that I want to host a project on, which I then want to work on from my local machine. I have tried using VSCode on my MacBook to work on the files before re-uploading them to the web server with SFTP, and then running the project server-side with `dotnet run`. This doesn't work, however, because it doesn't open port 5000 externally so I'm unable to view the project.

This probably just comes down to how much of a novice I am when it comes to ASP.NET. How do you or your organisation go about working on a project based on a server? Do I need to install the core on my local machine and run it locally before uploading changes back to the server with SFTP, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you created virtual directory or website in server ? Where you uploaded the code ? What is it with port 5000 ?

Comment: Port 5000 is the one which is used when you run the app with `dotnet run` AFAIK

Comment: No that's .net internal Webserver, but in vps you need to install on iis

Comment: I see, that must be what I'm missing. The VPS is a Debian droplet, can Apache be used instead of IIS?

Comment: By default iis uses port 80 to serve web requests which is open on server, you don't need to do anything

Comment: No you can't use Apache for asp.net afaik, you install mono and try

Comment: I'll give that a try tomorrow, thanks for your help @Krishna

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: @Krishna, I'm still confused here. When I use `dotnet run` to run the project, it publishes it to `http://localhost:5000`. I want to expose this to the internet, but I'm unable to do so. I have tried changing the exposed url to `http://*:5000` but it still doesn't let me browse to the project from my local machine.